# How to understand "that has sent economic forecasters the world over..."?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

This is the original sentence:

> [...] that **has sent economic forecasters the world** over scurrying to revise down their predictions.

I want to know what "send sb the world" means, and what does "over" mean.

Why does the sentence use "over", and what does "revise down" mean. And I also want to know how to understand this sentence. My understanding is "because the dates economic forecasters have forecast are wrong, maybe overestimated, so that scurries economic forecasters to revise their forecast dates to fell.

Comment: hello.could you tell me what "the wold " mean.i don't know its explanition in this sentence .sorry for my unreadable paragraph,actually my english gramma is bad.and how to understand this sentence?

Comment: **the world over=all over the world**. You still need to punctuate better. Capital letters and periods.

Comment: You can correct your grammar in Word before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you quote a sentence, you should make sure to start it with a capital letter and that it is accurate. The actual sentence is:
"That has sent economic forecasters the world over scurrying to revise down their predictions."
"That" is some information about the covid-19 pandemic.
"The world over" is an idiom, meaning the same as "all around the world". Here, it means that the economic forecasters they are talking about are in many parts of the world.
Economic forecasters make predictions about the economic future.
"Revise down" means that they are changing their predictions (revising), and they are decreasing them (down).
I am adding this to make something clearer - the word "scurrying" is not transitive. It's a figure of speech, describing frantic activity on the part of the economic forecasters. "Scurrying" is the running around of small animals when they are alarmed or excited.
The rest of your question is too garbled to understand.

Comment: They are not *decreasing* them. They are giving lower numbers. the idiom is: to send [someone scurrying]. The poster has used scurry incorrectly.

Comment: The forecasters are hurrying (scurrying) to lower their predictions (to decrease them). The sentence as I quoted it is from "www.economist.com". Google it yourself.

Comment: revise down a prediction is right. decrease a prediction is not. Decrease predictions would mean: making fewer predictions. That was my point.

Comment: I disagree. "Decreasing" could mean what you said, but it's an unlikely interpretation.

Comment: The Economist does not say: "decrease their predictions"/. It says in black and white: to revise down their predictions.

Comment: That's right. It was I who glossed that as "decreased their predictions". I'm still happy with the way I expressed it. Have a good day.